# A Problem on Improper Integrals

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Let $f(x)$ be continuous except at $x = 0$ and let $a > 0$. Assume that the improper integral $$\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\,dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0+}\int_{\epsilon}^{a}f(x)\,dx$$ exists and let $$g(x) = \int_{x}^{a}\frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt$$ Show that $$\int_{0}^{a}g(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{a}f(x)\,dx$$

I tried integration by parts noting that $g'(x) = -f(x)/x$ and obtained for $0 < \epsilon < a$ the following $$\int_{\epsilon}^{a}g(x)\,dx = [xg(x)]_{x = \epsilon}^{x = a} - \int_{\epsilon}^{a}xg'(x)\,dx$$ or $$\int_{\epsilon}^{a}g(x)\,dx = -\epsilon g(\epsilon) + \int_{\epsilon}^{a}f(x)\,dx$$

The problem is solved if we can somehow show that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+}\epsilon g(\epsilon) = 0$. Looking at the definition $g(x)$ we see that we have no information of the behavior of $f(t)$ at $t = 0$ and the $t$ in denominator complicates the analysis of $g(\epsilon)$. Please suggest some hints which can lead to the solution.

Note: This problem is taken from G. H. Hardy's "A Course of Pure Mathematics" 10th ed. Page 397.

Comment: I would like to do something like this :

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \int_{\varepsilon}^{a} g(x) \; dx & = & \int_{\varepsilon}^{a} \Big( \int_{x}^{a} \frac{f(t)}{t} \; dt \Big) \; dx \\
 & = & \int_{\varepsilon}^{a} \int_{0}^{a} \frac{f(t)}{t} 1_{\left\{ t \geq x \right\}} dt dx \\
 & = & \int_{0}^{a} \Big( \int_{0}^{t} \; dx \Big) \frac{f(t)}{t} \; dt \\
 & = & \int_{\varepsilon}^{a} f(t) \; dt 
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

using Fubini's theorem. But one has to prove that we can actually switch the order of integrals. I mean : this may be an idea but it is not rigorous.

Comment: To jibounet: The justification for changing order of integration may not be simple. Plus this question is in a book which does not talk at all about multiple integrals. Maybe some nice technique with single variable calculus would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Define 
$$h(x)=\int_x^af(t)dt,\ \forall x\in[0,a].$$
Then for every $x\in(0,a]$,
$$g(x)=-\int_x^a\frac{h'(t)}{t}dt=\frac{h(x)}{x}-\int_x^a\frac{h(t)}{t^2}dt=\frac{h(x)}{a}+\int_x^a\frac{h(x)-h(t)}{t^2}dt.$$

Given  $\delta\in(0, a]$, denote 
$$M_\delta=\max_{x,y\in[0,\delta]}|h(x)-h(y)|.$$
When $x\in(0,\delta)$, 
$$|g(x)-\frac{h(x)}{a}|\le \int_x^\delta\frac{|h(x)-h(t)|}{t^2}dt+\int_\delta^a\frac{|h(x)-h(t)|}{t^2}dt\le \frac{M_\delta}{x}+\frac{M_a}{\delta}.$$

Comment: How does this make $xg(x)$ tend to zero as $x \to 0+$?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I wrote my answer in this way because I thought you would prefer a hint rather than a full answer. Is it better if I add all the details to my answer?

Comment: @Landscape   en, This proof is correct! well done!

Comment: @ziangchen: No, it was flawed, and now it's corrected. My brain is a little unclear today and I mistakenly thought $h(0)=0$ before. Thank you!

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Terribly sorry! I  mistakenly thought $h(0)=0$ before. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Landscape  Your idea is right! this is the most important part!

Comment: @ziangchen: Thank you again for your appreciation.

Comment: Great Landscape! You get +1 and the bounty.

Comment: It seems bounty can't be awarded unless it is 24hrs from start of bounty. Anyways thanks a lot!

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: You are welcome! I still feel sorry about misleading you with a flawed argument. Maybe I I shouldn't post any answer when my head is not clear enough. Don't worry about the bounty; you can wait until the bounty expires to see if there is a better answer.

Comment: No need to feel sorry. Same thing has happened with me on math.se. As you wish I will wait for bounty to expire and see if a better answer comes.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Thank you for your tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

To prove  $\lim\limits_{x\to0}xg(x)= 0$, let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $ x_0$ such that $ 0<x<x_0 \implies |\int_x^{x_0}f(t)\, dt|<\epsilon$. For such $ x $ we have

$$ xg(x) = x\int_{x_0}^a\frac{f(t)}{t}dt+x\int_{x}^{x_0}\frac{f(t)}{t}dt$$

The first term on the right $\to 0$ as $x\to 0^+$. To estimate the second term, set $ F(x) = \int_x^{x_0}f(t)\,dt$ and integrate by parts:

$$ \int_{x}^{x_0}\frac{f(t)}{t}dt =\frac{-F(t)}{t}\bigg |_{x}^{x_0}-\int_{x}^{x_0}\frac{F(t)}{t^2}dt$$

the fact that $|F|<\epsilon $

$$|x\int_{x}^{x_0}\frac{f(t)}{t}dt| < 3\epsilon $$

We get that $\limsup\limits_{x\to 0^+} |xg(x)|\le 3\epsilon$

Comment: Please check definition of $g(x)$. If $f(x) = 1$, then $g(x) = \log(a/x)$ and clearly $\lim_{x \to 0+}g(x)$ does not exist.

Answer (score -1):

1. find g'(x)=-f(x)/x
2. x*g'(x)=f(x)
3. integrate  both side with limit 0 to a using integration by parts
4. {x*g(x)|0 to a } - { integration of g(x) limit 0 to a} = -{integration of  f(x) limit 0 to a }
5. now use given equation and put x =a than u will get g(a)=0
6. now just solve u will get the desired result .

Comment: I have mentioned this procedure in my question. The only problem is to evaluate $x g(x)$ when $x$ is $0$ as we have no idea what is $g(0)$ or whether it exists or not. Please read the question carefully.